# display category with background color

Tags: categories, taxonomy

i'm new in the wordpress developpment. i started coding my first theme and i want to dispay categories with color, each category has his own color. in wordpress i know that we have  :
category name -
category link
and i want to add category color for example.

Note :  without plugin or costum field but i can add a lot of colors to css file if that's help.

```
  <div class="category">
        <a href="#">
     <span style="background: <?php echo $cats[0]->color ;?>"><?php echo $cats[0]->name; ?></span>
        </a> // this my idea i don't know if that's working or not
   </div>
```

[image: exemple]

Comment: Welcome. Might look into [post_class()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_class/) and use CSS class names instead of inline color styling with PHP in classic/hyprid themes.

Comment: @birgire thank you for your reply yes that's help for just replacing the class name i want to set a color to each category and when i want to get the category name i will be able to get the category color too, for example red color for Food category

Answer (score 0):

I would add the category slug as a class to each category link, and change your class name to be more specific so other CSS doesn't conflict on accident:

```html
<div class="category-link">
    <a href="#" class="<?= $cats[0]->slug ?>"><?= $cats[0]->name ?></a>
</div>
```

Then call the class with CSS:

```css
.category-link .food {
    background-color: red;
}
```